# What values to pass in for safeTxGas and gasPrice?

Tags: gnosis-safe

We're looking to support both sponsored and non-sponsored transactions, both work fine actually, but I can't find anywhere, for non-sponsored transactions, what should the fields `safeTxGas` and `gasPrice` be. I can pass 1 for them and I get a little amount in return, however I don't see the relation between it and the value 1 that I pass in and what ends up getting refunded. Example of a transaction using these values [here](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x0566b01c24950557b80420d55790bf95bc7dd7c7af06b77d052d4e1504ce883b)(polygonscan transaction).

I read [this](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/a6504a9afdeac186a8cdb29ad68b189523c80eda/docs/safe_tx_gas.md) but I don't think it explicitly tells what these fields are, and more specifically, how should the values be calculated.

I'm assuming there's a formula to calculate this but I'm not even sure what should I be looking for... Thank you in advance for any comments and suggestions.